# Why is my op/s decreasing?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, nosql

Using cassandra-stress I am generating a write operation of 50 million writes and then a mixed operation (1write and 3reads) for 20minutes. I'm repeating this process number of times.
After each iteration the operation rate is decreasing and the total operation time is increasing as shown in image.

[image: Write operations for 3 iterations]

Answer (score 0):

The decreased op/s usually indicates that your reads/writes takes longer to execute. The root cause cannot be determined without inspecting carefully what's your C* cluster is doing.

I can be as general as the information I have:

- You have a wrong JVM settings, eg your cluster is performing poorly because C* starts experiencing long GC pauses, so check your GC log files and tune the JVM accordingly.
- You did nothing wrong. C* starts to perform more and more disk IO for compactions, and the overall throughput decreases because you simply run out of IOPS. Use the `nodetool compactionstats` command to understand if compactions accumulates over time during your stress (and they complete successfully once the stress finishes), or they complete while you're stressing the system (so you don't have any IOPS problems at all). Check your `concurrent_compactors` settings in your YAML file.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. I checked for nodetool compactionstats and it shows that the pending tasks are 0. The concurrent_compactors setting has been commented in yaml file. I'm a beginner in Cassandra.

Comment: When I run the same operation repeatedly, initially I get average op/s around 65k and it slowly decreases to 30k. I usually clear my data by deleting contents of cassandra/data/data and cassandra/logs before running every iteration

Comment: @MohitVellanki Have you checked some stats with `nodetool cfhistograms`?

Comment: No. I haven't used nodetool cfhistograms